# "...a un gestor de residuos"??? What is it in English?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

I was translating a certificate from a crematorium but I got stuck at the last paragraph. It says

> "... entregamos las prótesis no consumidas en la incineración a un **gestor de residuos**."

I do understand the most of it but I have no idea how I should translate `a un gestor de residuos` into English. What is the English equivalent? Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Gestión de residuos` podría ser `waste management` o incluso `Hazardous Waste Management` si son peligrosos para el medio ambiente o la salud.

Dado el contexto, ignoro si "manager" (waste manager) sería la mejor traducción, y debería ser un "(Hazardous) Waste agent/factory/plant/...".

I think that the best translation would be

> We give any prothesis not consumed in the incineration/cremation to a waste management facility.

Comment: Gracias, Diego! So, if I say "the manager of the waste management facility", would it be acceptable or a stretch?

Comment: Well, you don't really give it to the manager, like if you were giving these wastes "in hand", and certainly you don't give it to a high rank manager (in any case, maybe to some other kind of employee: a driver worker, etc.). These wastes are delivered to (or pick up by) the facility. So I would be more prone to translate as "we give any unconsumed prothesis to a waste management facility". I'll edit the answer to include this.

Comment: Diego, you are fantastic! Thank you very much for your great insight!!